# How to trigger click event only for the clicked-on layer and not its parent too

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xvkM/5/)

I can of course take the `.inner` layer out of `.main` layer
and then use absolute position against another wrapper i.e `.outer` layer
to place it in the same position and this will stop it from triggering `.main` click event. 
but I was wondering if there's an easier way to avoid having both click events fire if both child
element and parent trigger a click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `stopPropagation()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outer').on("click",".main",function() { alert('main clicked'); })
    $('.outer').on("click",".inner",function(e) {e.stopPropagation(); alert('inner clicked'); })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xvkM/6/

Answer (score 1):

[Use `stopPropagation()`](http://jsfiddle.net/5xvkM/7/). Even if both are delegated events, jQuery evaluates them deepest first. Since the inner most has `stopPropagation()`, the events higher up in the order are not executed.

```
$('.outer').on("click", ".inner", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('inner clicked');
});
```

But you'll have to note the order of execution between direct handlers and delegated handlers. Since events need to bubble to reach the delegated handlers, direct handlers are fired first. Stopping propagation using delegated handlers would be [useless when direct handlers are in the mix](http://jsfiddle.net/5xvkM/10/).